# Trying to find certain fields on the magento database without success

Tags: magento-1.9

I was trying to find some fields because i want to obtain all the products and then, make a query but i was not able to do that(they dont appear in the database diagram for Magento 1.9):

This is the diagram:

[image: diagram]
https://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png

I only found the fields **"SKU"** and **"min_sale_qty"**. What happened to the others?

Do these fields : code_brand, code_business_unit, code_line, code_group, code_business even exist or they were created by someone?

[image]

Anyway, i am using MYSQL connected to the MAGENTO database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

products in Magento are EAV models, which leads to most attributes not having an own column in the catalog_product_entity table.

If you are searching for a specific attribute value of a specific product you first have to go into the eav_attribute table, search the attribute you are looking for (by attribute_code for example) and get the id and type of the attribute.

For example values of the type text are saved in the catalog_product_entity_text table.
To get the value you can filter it by product id (entity_id) and attribute_id. (There can still be multiple values for each store. store_id=0 is the default value).

The easiest way to get the values would be using the product repository (as it handles all needed db joins in the background for you).

If you must use sql to get the data you have to join the tables corresponding to your needs

Comment: Thank you for replying!. Can i access this table *eav_attribute*  directly using a query? (select * from + table name). If so, after executing that query i have to look for this fields: (sku, code_brand, code_business_unit, code_line, code_group, code_business, min_sale_qty), get their id and type of the attribute. Am i right? How can i find those that are not type text?.
Anyway, how can get the product repository?

Comment: Dude, if you have a little time off, can check my question:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260205/not-getting-the-correct-values-while-trying-to-get-all-the-products
You are the one who knows!